# Html 5 video with dynamic source not working in android

Tags: javascript, android, html, phonegap-build

Html5 Video with dynamic source loaded using javascript working fine with web browser but not working in android phonegap build application

Source code as follows:

Javascript code:

```
$('#video_player').append('
  <video width="320" height="240" controls>
    <source src="'+ response.video_url +'" type="video/mp4">
  </video>');
```

Html code:

```
<div id="video_player"></div>
```

Video working fine in android when code written as bellow:

Html code:

```
<div id="video_player">
    <video width="320" height="240" controls>
        <source src="test_video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

My best guess would be that it has something to do with Cross Origin Resource Sharing, which is a problem when you try to access a resource from a different domain.

See this guide for how to solve it: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.4.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html#Whitelist%20Guide

Basically add the following to your `config.xml`:

```
<access origin="*" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with IE9 once. I solved it by explicitly creating a source element rather than appending a string of html. You might give that a try

ex:

```
var mp4 = document.createElement('source');
mp4.src = response.video_url;
mp4.type = 'video/mp4';
$('#video_player video').append(mp4);
```